# How to implement segment control with search bar within navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I was wondering if it is possible to add a `UISegmentedControl` with `UISearchBar` inside the same navigation bar?

I tried to minimize my `UISearchBar`, but it didn't work:

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar


}
```

I know apps like Apple Music have done this:

[image]
Whether the segment is part of the whole UISearchBar could also be a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.placeholder = "Biblioteket ditt"
searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.1)
searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Apple Music", "Biblioteket ditt"]

// To change UISegmentedControl color only when appeared in UISearchBar
UISegmentedControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .red

self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Here is the screenshot of above code:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I tried to add it to navigationItem like this: navigationItem.titleView = searchBar. It works but looks terrible. The navigation bar is not aligned with the segment.

Comment: I forgot to remove the back bar button, it works well now. I just have to change the colour of the scope. Thanks, this is the correct answer.